# Evaluting the given Definte Integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Assume that $f$ is positive on [0,5] and $\int_0^5f(x)dx= 3$, $f$ is negative on [5,7] and $\int_0^7 f(x)dx=-10$. Evaluate the following integrals

$$ \int_5^7f(x)dx,\int_5^0f(x)dx, \int_7^06f(x)dx, \int_0^7|f(x)|dx $$

For the first one I believe the answer is 30.

The second is -3.

The third one is 60.

Last one I think it might be -10 and 10. (not to sure).

I could be wrong because I think the intervals in the original questions might have an affect in the question.

Just want to know if I'm right or wrong.

Any help is appericated. Thanks!

Comment: $\int_0^5 + \int_5^7 = -10$, hence, $\int_5^7 = -10-3 = -13$

Comment: $\int_0^5 = - \int_5^0$

Comment: $\int_0^7|f(x)|dx = |\int_0^5| + |\int_5^7|$ since we know the sign doesn't change for each part

Comment: $\int 6 f = 6 \int f $

Comment: I thought you multiplied them, so we add them.

Comment: Nope, all additions. The answers then are $-13, -3, 60, 16$.

Comment: @Hamid for the absolute one, why would you add the 5 and 0 one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a question about the linearity of the integral. If you're confused about the linearity property, draw a picture. It'll illuminate everything geometrically. I'll show you how to do the first one, and you can do the same for the others.

We want to evaluate $$\int_5^7 f(x) dx$$ We know that $$\int_0^7 f(x)dx = -10$$ Then by linearity of the integral $$\int_5^7 f(x) dx = \int_0^7 f(x) dx - \int_0^5 f(x) dx = - 10 - 3 = - 13$$

Can you do the others?

Comment: I thought you multiple them. Would the second one be -3? and the third one would be 60?

Comment: @shawnedward  Both look solid to me!